# Cannot get new array to save

Tags: express, mongoose

I am working on getting a blog set up and I am having trouble getting my comments data associated with the individual blog post.  I am using Mongoose and Express.  I am trying to create a new posts and push it to the blog array, but the association is not saving.  I can see both the comment and blog objects in my DB individually when I pull up the Mongo shell, but they are not associated in the DB.  However, they are showing correctly in the console in the my route.

Here are my two relevant schemas that are up in different files.

Comment schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    desc: String,
    posted: {type: Date, default: Date.now()} 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

Blog schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    title: String,
    desc: String,
    posted: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ] 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);
```

Route:

```
app.post("/blogs/:id/comments", function(req, res){
    Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
        if(err){
            // console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/blogs");
        } else {
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comments){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    blog.comments.push(comments);
                    blog.save();
                    console.log(blog);
                    res.redirect("/blogs/" + blog._id);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

console results from above:

```
{ _id: 5a3ef348fcdd624a0c8416fb,
  title: 'Ah, a new post!',
  author: 'Lefty',
  desc: 'Here we are trying to see about fixing the issue with comments not being associated to the blog posts, but still being created.',
  __v: 0,
  comments:
   [ { _id: 5a3f06c0f33db14984baca92,
       desc: 'Save the turtles.',
       author: 'April',
       __v: 0,
       posted: 2017-12-24T01:45:16.864Z } ],
  posted: 2017-12-24T00:21:34.514Z }
```

Here is the information in my Mongo shell:

```
> db.blogs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a3ef348fcdd624a0c8416fb"), "title" : "Ah, a new post!", "author" : "Lefty", "desc" : "Here we are trying to see about fixing the issue with comments not being associated to the blog posts, but still being created.", "comments" : [ ], "posted" : ISODate("2017-12-24T00:21:34.514Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: It's because your schema isn't matched up proper with your data. It has `type` and `ref` when you're pushing in `desc` `author` etc. so it leaves comments blank since they don't match the expected schema.

Comment: I have tried to look at this a few times and I don't see what the problem is with my schema?  Would you please be able to say it a different way?